# how to add image literal to an array and show them?

Tags: ios, swift, image, swift3, imageview

I was trying to add image literals to array and display them as per the index.

Here is my code :

```
var images = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "male-circle-128"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "add_to_favourite-128"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "28468-200"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "progress_circular"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "logout-1-128")]
```

and showing like this

`cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(cgImage: images[indexPath.row] as! CGImage)`

got EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION! what is the proper way to do this

[image]

Comment: Don't getting why you are getting crash on declaration of array because it is working perfectly for me.

Comment: @EricAya no UIImage only

Comment: No..its crashing when I'm adding those elements to the array.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me, i just tested with iOS 10 & Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: https://gist.github.com/iBlahji/4a8d5109594d0f21f7d6ae844a1970b7 Check this , it works

Answer (score 2):

let images:[UIImage] = [array of image literal goes here]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create array of image literals like:

```
var images = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image1"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you cast to `CGImage` , your literals are `UIImage` and you can use them without casting and even if you want `CGImage` use the initializer not casting.

```
    let images = [literal images are here]
    imageview.image = images[indexPath.row]
```